# Javascript: Calculate height of DIV minus pixels

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently looking for a javascript to do a math calculation for me. I'm looking for something that will read the height of an entire window (not screen size), minus 100px from that value, and then output in to, lets say, a style value. Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the height of a div, you can use the property innerHeight, something like:

```
var height = document.getElementById('somediv').innerHeight;
```

Then, you can do the calculations you need on this variable, and use later in something like:

```
document.getElementById('otherdiv').style.height = height + 'px';
```

Comment: Ooo I like that! But is it possible to calculate the height of the entire window instead? This is what I have going so far, it doesn't seem to be filling, which is why the window idea might work.

var height = document.getElementById('#maindiv').innerHeight;

document.getElementById('#seconddiv').style.height = height + '-100px';